# perl: reverse values in a column

Tags: perl

I have a tab-seperated table (table1) with 4 columns, looking like this

```
A       +       1      1
A       +       2      2
A       +       3      3
B       -       2      4
B       -       3      5
B       -       4      6
B       -       5      7
C       +       1      8
C       +       2      9
C       +       3      10
D       -       1      11
D       -       2      12
D       -       3      13
```

The letters in col1 define groups. Now, if there is a "+" in col2, I just want to keep the line as it is. If there i a "-" in col2, I want to reverse the values in col3, for all lines belonging to the group defined by col1. For this example the output should look like this

```
A       +       1       1
A       +       2       2
A       +       3       3
B       -       5       4
B       -       4       5
B       -       3       6
B       -       2       7
C       +       1       8
C       +       2       9
C       +       3       10
D       -       3       11
D       -       2       12
D       -       1       13
```

So for group A, everything stays the same. But for group B the original values in col3 are: 2, 3, 4, 5. They should become 5, 4, 3, 2. The rest of the columns stays the same.

How should I work this out in Perl?

Comment: Hello. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service - such things exist, but they usually cost money. It's a site for programmers to help other programmers with their problems. You don't have to be a _good_ programmer to participate - we all started somewhere - but you do have to make a good faith effort to solve your own problem, and expand a bit on where you're having difficulty. Please see [ask] for more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution that makes use of the advantage of random access if you read the data into memory

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = map { chomp; [ split /\t/ ]; } <DATA>;

my %ranges;
for ( grep $_->[1] eq '-',  @data ) {
  push @{ $ranges{$_->[0]} }, $_;
}

for my $range ( values %ranges ) {
  for ( my $i = 0; $i*2 < $#$range; ++$i ) {
    my ($from, $to) = @{$range}[$i, $#$range-$i];
    ( $from->[2], $to->[2] ) = ( $to->[2], $from->[2] );
  }
}

print join("\t", @$_), "\n" for @data;

__DATA__
col1    col2    col3    col4
A   +   1   10
A   +   2   20
A   +   3   35
B   -   2   5
B   -   3   21
B   -   4   23
B   -   5   36
```

**output**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A   +   1   10
A   +   2   20
A   +   3   35
B   -   5   5
B   -   4   21
B   -   3   23
B   -   2   36
```

Comment: Please note my update, which makes the algorithm a little clearer

Answer (score 5):

Keep the lines of a `-` group in a buffer, output it when the group changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub output {
    my $buffer = shift;
    my @rev = map $_->[2], @$buffer;
    $_->[2] = pop @rev for @$buffer;  # Reverse the 3rd column.
    print join("\t", @$_) for @$buffer;
    @$buffer = ();
}

my @buffer;
my $group;
print scalar <>; # header
while (<>) {
    my @cols = split /\t/;

    if (@buffer and $cols[0] ne $group) {
        output(\@buffer);
    }

    if ('+' eq $cols[1]) {
        print;
    } else {
        $group = $cols[0];
        push @buffer, \@cols;
    }
}
output(\@buffer) if @buffer;  # Don't forget to output the last buffer.
```

Comment: did you try the code yourself? It's not working when there are two groups with "-" below each other.